# Create an array in php in the following format

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array in this format

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [page_id] => 132
            [link] => Savings
            [count] => 5
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [page_id] => 172
            [link] => Coverage
            [count] => 5
        )    



)
```

I wish to convert this into the following format

```
Array
(
    [Savings] => Array
        (
            [132] => 3
            [172] => 5
        )

    [Coverage] => Array
        (
            [132] => 9
            [172] => 9
        )

)
```

I have tried the following code and getting result in the below format.

```
foreach($result_link as $data) {                

        $page_array[$data->link][] = array( $data->page_id => $data->count );        
    }

    print_r($page_array);
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Where does the `Coverage` count of `9` come from??

Comment: From where the `3 & 5` came in `[132] => 3  ,   [172] => 5`

Comment: It's a big array, and unable to post the code in here with question. so i cut some item from the array

Comment: Not saying to post the full code. Instead try to post the required code to understand the problem.

Comment: I have confusion here         $page_array[$data->link][] = array( $data->page_id => $data->count );

Comment: I am getting the result in this format. [Savings] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [132] => 5
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [172] => 9
                )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get what you are after from what you have provided... This might help.

```
<?php
$test_array = array(
        (object)array('page_id'=>'132','link'=>'Savings','count'=>5),
        (object)array('page_id'=>'133','link'=>'Savings','count'=>6),
        (object)array('page_id'=>'172','link'=>'Coverage','count'=>7),
        (object)array('page_id'=>'173','link'=>'Coverage','count'=>8),
        );

var_dump($test_array);

$new_array = array();
// Create the new array
foreach($test_array as $object){
    $new_array[$object->link][$object->page_id] = $object->count;
}


var_dump($new_array);
```

Which gives a result of

```
array (size=2)
  'Savings' => 
    array (size=2)
      132 => int 5
      133 => int 6
  'Coverage' => 
    array (size=2)
      172 => int 7
      173 => int 8
```

**NOTE:** This only works if your page_id's are unique for each link.

Comment: You are welcome. You provided enough information to work it out, which helped.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

lemme know if you have any query

```
$tmp = [];
foreach($result_link as $data){
  $tmp[$data->link][$data->page_id] = $data->count;
}
```